# Why the output of transfer-learning keeps changing?

Tags: python, feature-extraction, transfer-learning

I am using the pretrained Alex-Net model to extract the features of some images in the Fc7 (right before the classification). Every time I extract the 4096 features from each image, they change ... why?

Comment: Just to clarify that those different features belong to the same image in your case? If so then share your code.

Comment: Hi @AbhishekPrajapat, yes! for the same image the features change in each of the runs. I notice that in my code:  
`layer = 'Fc7'
alexNet = models.alexnet(pretrained=True)
new_classifier = nn.Sequential(*list(alexNet.classifier.children())[:-1])
alexNet.classifier = new_classifier`
**I was missing alexNet.eval()** so I think that's the reason